# Sync Firebase 'dependencies' with Gradle

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to add firebase to my app, every time I add firebase's dependencies it shows this error!
Image:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Have you added `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` in your repositories?

Comment: You seem to have an error in line `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'` Try to solve that first!

Comment: Yes i have added maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } in my repositories.

Comment: when i remove Firebase dependencies, the implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2' error is gone. and when i add them once again the error is showing.

Comment: i don't know what else to do, please help!

Answer (score 0):

use this code inside the build.gradle(Project)

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'



        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and correct library use

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: if a problem is not solved so please screenshot of both gradle files. Thank You